# After assign number to variables, how to print variables that has a certain value?

Tags: python, list

For example, I have:

```
A = 0.13
B = 0.32
C = 0.56
D = 0.72
E = 0.91
```

and I only want to append the variables that has value greater than 0.35 to some list (say LIST = []). The result would be something like:

```
LIST = [C, D, E]
```

Where do I start? What functions are necessary to import to get the job done.

......................................................................................

I want the program to print the variables (A, B, C, ...), not the values (0.13, 0.32, ...)
The replies I've got so far are printing the values.

So far I've tried dict approach:

```
dict = {"A":0.13, "B":0.32, "C":0.56, "D":0.72, "E":0.91}
```

but I do not know how to set condition for dict.values()

For example

```
for dict.values() > 0.35:
    print dict.keys()
```

Does not work.

Comment: Those are not strings, those are variables...

Answer (score 1):

First, don't put them in separate variables to begin with. Put them in a list.

```
nums = [0.13, 0.32, 0.56, 0.72, 0.91]
```

That way, you aren't limited to five numbers and you don't have to come up with variable names for each of them. Plus, you can easily iterate over them and process each the same way.

If you already have the five variables defined for some other purpose, then just make a list of them:

```
nums = [A, B, C, D, E]
```

Either way, you can then make another list with only the numbers you want:

```
highnums = [n for n in nums if n > 0.35]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have all of your variable initially in an array,

```
numbers = [.13, .32, .56, .72, .91]
```

and then use a list comphrension to eliminate the ones you don't want

```
reduced_numbers = [x for x in numbers if x > .35]
```

and then print the result

```
print reduced_numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set it up, you would have to compare each item, and if it's greater than your threshold (0.35) in this case, you would append it to an array.

For example:

```
A = 0.13
B = 0.32
C = 0.56
D = 0.72
E = 0.91
threshold = 0.35
list = []

if (A > threshold):
  list.append(A)
if (B > threshold):
  list.append(B)
if (C > threshold):
  list.append(C)
if (D > threshold):
  list.append(D)
if (E > threshold):
  list.append(E)
```

Might I suggest storing the numbers in an array instead, then iterating through it and adding it to list using the same logic?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> numbers = [.13, .32, .56, .72, .91]
>>> filter(lambda i: i > 0.35, numbers)
[0.56, 0.72, 0.91]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) to get there.
First, you need your data to start in some sort of iterable.
Let's use a tuple:

```
my_data = (0.13, 0.32, 0.56, 0.72, 0.91)
```

Then use a list comprehension to construct your list:

```
my_list = [x for x in my_data if x > 0.35]
```